# Using polymorphism in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

been struggling to find a solution to this...

What is the equivalent of the following c# in vb?

```
var v = something as control;
```

Been trying for a while and haven't really found much, the following is what i have managed to get to so far.

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is Control Then
   'what to put here? 
   ctrl = ctrl as control??? 'nope...      
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is Control Then
   ctrl = Directcast(ctrl, control)
End If
```

Comment: No, but same as the answer i've just found, Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: this may provide useful info as well [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056514/difference-between-directcast-and-ctype-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that seems to work well.

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is Control Then
    ctrl = CType(ctrl, Control)
End If
```

using explicit Casting.