# Casting and converting

Tags: vb.net, casting, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

there are an array of options for casting in VB.NET and I wanted to clarify my understanding.

**DIRECTCAST**

Please see the code below:

```
Dim p as New PostGraduate
Dim s as student = directcast(p,student)
```

This is a CAST rather than a conversion.  Therefore the reference changes to a Student and the value is still a PostGraduate.

**cstr and ctype**

Please see the code below:

```
dim l as long=100
dim i as integer = cstr(l)
dim j as integer = ctype(l,integer)
```

These are both conversions so the reference and value changes to an integer.  cstr and ctype are identical.  cstr and ctype call Convert.ToString, Convert.ToInt etc behind the scenes.  How is a custom object e.g. Student converted (Object.ToString?)

**DataReader.getString (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and DataReader.getOrdinal (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

When should these be used? Do they call convert.ToString behind the scenes?

I am confused why there are so many different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: The question is based on a nonsensical example.  No DirectCast is required and no conversion is needed.  Option Strict On does not require you to write code like this.  You'll have to come up with a real problem.

Comment: @hans passant, i have removed all references to option strict. Is the question ok now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between DirectCast() and CType() in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056514/difference-between-directcast-and-ctype-in-vb-net)

Comment: the first line in each link explains the difference. .GetString returns the **string value** of column; .GetOrdinal returns the **integer ordinal** of a column, two very different things both in data type and data meaning.  This line fails under Option Strict: `dim i as integer = cstr(l)`.  Neither i nor j needs to involve strings at all except that your code uses CSr to convert a long to integer;  neither calls Convert.ToInt, `i` uses an internal VB `ToInteger` function  (or `ToString` to handle the `CInt(Cstr(long))` code). Your `j = CType(l` gets optimized out and becomes a checked cast.