# How to implement the DirectCast operator in a type?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, casting, type-conversion

When implementing the `CType` operator in a custom Type like this one below, the Type is not casteable using `DirectCast` operator:

```
Public Structure ColorInfo
    ...
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal colorInfo As ColorInfo) As Color

        Return Color.FromArgb(colorInfo.R, colorInfo.G, colorInfo.B)

    End Operator
    ...
End Structure
```

On the other hand it is directly assignable to a `Color` object, which is very confussing:

```
Dim obj As color = MyColorInfo
```

Then, I would like to implement the `DirectCast` operator firstly to obtain typing comfort in my environment (instead of using the `CType`) and secondly to obtain the beneffits, if any, of what explains the MSDN docs **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx)**:

> DirectCast does not use the Visual Basic run-time helper routines for
>   conversion, so it can provide somewhat better performance than CType
>   when converting to and from data type Object.

How I can implement it in **C#** or **Vb.Net**?.

Comment: Consider `TryCast` method

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for comment, but I don't like the behavior of **TryCast** because it does not raise an exception if conversion fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between DirectCast() and CType() in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056514/difference-between-directcast-and-ctype-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DirectCast` is a 'compile-time' cast with added type-checking at runtime. It's meant for casting when type inheritance or interface implementation are in play.
It will not consider user defined casts, such as you have here, so it's not applicable.

`CType` is appropriate and you should just use that, rather than trying to subvert the language. It will look for user defined conversions and apply them.

Performance-wise, the `CType` is as good as it gets here. Because the types are known at compile time in your example, you'll get the optimal code for it.

---

*To address the comment:* The principal thing is that you, as a programmer, do nothing for `DirectCast`, VB.NET does everything. In fact, you **can't** do anything to get a `DirectCast` other than starting your class with implementing a particular interface or inheriting from a base class.

If you want to provide any other conversions, then you use `CType`. This is a fundamental split between the two. `DirectCast` comes automatically and you can't modify its behaviour. `CType` will allow you to extend its behaviour by providing custom conversions.

So to summarise: either your class inherits from a type, in which case `DirectCast` of an instance to and from that base type works, or it doesn't, in which case you need to create your own `CType` override.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but then, for those classes which inherits from other types, how do I apply a **DirectCast** implementation?. I didn't find any example in MSDN. thanks again

Comment: @ElektroStudios Say we have a TextBox instance but typed as Control (returned from Form.Controls for example) and we want to use something specific to TextBox we can use DirectCast because what we really have IS a Textbox (and it wasn't we'll get an exception at runtime). DirectCast just allow to change the "point of view" over a variable, but really does nothing (the TextBox instance stay the same all the time) and that's (partly) why a DirectCast **can** be faster than a CType

Comment: @ElektroStudios I've tried to address your comment in an update to my answer, in addition to what Sehnsucht already said.