# How to find the text of a clicked Button in one single statement?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

So, basically, I'm programming this virtual keyboard, and I have to write code individually for each key, which are Buttons.
This is ridiculously tedious and I was wondering if there was maybe one single statement that could find the text of the key (`Button`) pressed.

My current code is like this:

```
textbox.TextBox1.Text = textbox.TextBox1.Text + zh.Text
```

`zh` is the name of a `Button`, for context.

Now, I have to copy and paste this string of code over and over in each Button's `Click` event.
I would think that there is a way to have the code grab the text of whatever `Button` I press, then send that text to the `TextBox`.

If this is indeed possible, would anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**:
Using the Designer, assign a single Click event to all your Buttons, then use the `sender` object, casting it to Button or Control:

```
Private Sub MyKeys_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyKeysA.Click, MyKeysB.Click, (...)
    TextBox1.AppendText(CType(sender, Button).Text)
End Sub
```

But the final event handler will have a lot of Buttons references attached to it. Not a beauty.

**Method 2**:
Create an event handler in code and assign it to all of your Buttons, using a *classic* delegate, with
`AddHandler [Event], AddressOf [HandlerMethodName]`

Assume that your Buttons have a common partial name, here **`"btnKey"`**.
You could also use the [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag) property and assign it a specific value(s) for your Keys Buttons.
You would then write in `Where()`: `b.Tag.ToString().Contains("[Some Common Identifier]")`.

> Note that the `Tag` property value is of type `Object`, so
> `Contains()` is just a generic example. It could evaluate to an
> Integer type or anything else.

**Note 1:** To assign a common identifier to all the Keys Buttons, you can use the Form Designer: select all the Buttons and use the Properties Window to change the `Tag` property of all the selected Buttons.

- Here, assuming all Controls are child of the Form. Specify the actual Parent if's a different Container

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Where(Function(b) b.Name.Contains("btnKey"))
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.MyKeys_Click
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MyKeys_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    TextBox1.AppendText(DirectCast(sender, Control).Text)
End Sub
```

**Note 2**:
As Andrew Morton suggested in the comments, here the cast is performed using the [DirectCast()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator) operator. Since `sender` **is** a Button and also Button derives from Control, you can use the *light-weight* `DirectCast()` to *see* `sender` as a Button or as a Control (since Button derives from Control and the `Text` property is inherited from Control) and access its `Text` property.

> From the Docs:
> [`DirectCast()`] *(...) it can provide somewhat better performance than CType
> when converting to and from data type Object.*

I'm leaving [CType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function) in the first example as a visual aide.

[Difference between DirectCast() and CType() in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056514/difference-between-directcast-and-ctype-in-vb-net?answertab=active#tab-top)

**Method 3**:
Create an event handler in code and assign it to all of your Buttons using a Lambda as a method delegate:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Where(Function(b) b.Name.Contains("btnKey"))
        AddHandler btn.Click, Sub() TextBox1.AppendText(btn.Text)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You might as well use DirectCast instead of CType because you already know that they are buttons. Further reading: [Difference between DirectCast() and CType() in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3056582/1115360).

Comment: @Andrew Morton  Hmm, yes, it's worth mentioning, since it'll work casting to both Button and Control here. I'll link the link :)

Comment: @Jimi What is textbox in `textbox.TextBox1` used in all three methods?

Comment: @Mary  I'm not sure. You should ask the OP, it's in the question's code snippet. Maybe, it's just the Form container Name (is it a text editor Form?), or another container control. I just followed the *existing pattern*. But this is probably not a great idea, in a more generic use case scenario (also because, apparently, generates the question *what's that for?*). I'm removing it.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, I was pasting it into my code bank and was wondering.

Comment: Your approaches using `For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)`, are ASSUMING that all of the Buttons are directly contained by the Form itself. They won't be found if they are in a different container, like a Panel. Obviously, you could change `Me` to the name of the Panel, like `Panel1`, but what if the controls are spread out between multiple containers? Then you'd either need to use a RECURSIVE search, or possibly instead use the `Controls.Find()` method to look for them "by name", specifying a recursive search.

Comment: @JImi, sorry about that. I occasionally don't notice the dates on posts that show up in my feed. I'll try to pay closer attention!

Comment: @Idle_Mind No problem, your observation is nonetheless correct. I'll add a note