# VB Ctype equivalent to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, ctype

```
ServerInfo = CType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(BufferPtr, GetType(SERVER_INFO_100)), SERVER_INFO_100)
```

I need to convert this `CType` to C#. I am not aware on VB.net. Please suggest how to do this and also forloop

```
For index = 0 To iEntriesRead - 1
```

Comment: You also have `SERVER_INFO_100 serverInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<SERVER_INFO_100>(bufferPtr);` No cast needed.

Comment: this works perfectly
'BufferPtr = CType(CType(BufferPtr, Long) + CType(Marshal.SizeOf(ServerInfo), Long), IntPtr)'

pleas convert this line too

Comment: I *think* the most direct equivalent of `CType` in VB is `Convert.ChangeType` in the .NET framework.  Note that this returns `object` so it would require a cast.

Answer (score 2):

[`CType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function) is a cast operator/function, so comparable to `(SERVER_INFO_100) object` in C#.

```
ServerInfo = (SERVER_INFO_100) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(BufferPtr, GetType(SERVER_INFO_100));
```

The closest you get to the C# cast operator is [`DirectCast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator) in VB.NET. Read:
[Difference between DirectCast() and CType() in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056514/difference-between-directcast-and-ctype-in-vb-net)

In C# you could also use the `as` cast operator which is the same as the VB.NET [`TryCast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/trycast-operator).

```
ServerInfo = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(BufferPtr, GetType(SERVER_INFO_100)) as SERVER_INFO_100;
```

This has the advantage that you don't get an exception if the type is not `SERVER_INFO_100`.

> Please suggest how to do this and also forloop

The [for-loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-for-statement) is explained in the docs.

Comment: While it's true that you don't get an `InvalidCastException` if the type is wrong with `as` (or `TryCast` in VB), you do then have to consider the possibility that you get `null`.  (This is a bit of a pet peeve of mine as I deal with a fair amount of code that uses `as` instead of a direct cast but then always treats it as if it succeeded... with this usage, it should be a direct cast so that you get the `InvalidCastException` on failure instead of a vague `NullReferenceException` later!)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "as" in C# for casting

For eg:

```
ServerInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure(BufferPtr, typeof(SERVER_INFO_100)) as SERVER_INFO_100;
```

For the For loop in C# you can follow below code

```
for(int index=0;index< iEntriesRead - 1;index++)
{
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Thank u for u r share...for For loop its ok...but where to give "as" for ctype

Comment: I don't have editor so I can not compile changes. I have modified answer. Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: You may need to continue that for-loop until `index<iEntriesRead` - then the last value will be iEntriesRead-1

Comment: `as` corresponds to VB `TryCast`.  You should never use `as` unless you are explicitly dealing with the potential `null`; in particular, if you pretend it's a plain cast, you are likely to convert an `InvalidCastException` at the point of conversion (very clear about what's wrong) to a `NullReferenceException` at some future access (much less clear about what's wrong).