# Clearing check boxes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I'm doing an assignment for Uni and in my VB.NET form I have some checkboxes, I'm trying to loop through and clear them (I have a button which will clear the form)

My problem is that there seems to be no property I can use to set the state of a checkbox when not explicitly telling VB which checkbox I want to use. for example, I can go

```
WineCheckBox.Checked = False
```

That will check the box, but I wand to DRY the code up a bit and not have to repeat this for each check box I have, this is what I was trying to do:

```
If TypeOf element Is CheckBox Then
    element.Checked = False
End If
```

I've tried using `element.CheckState` and `element.Checked` and both times I get "Checked (or CheckState) is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Control"

I've looked through all the attributes that I can find for this and none of them seem of use to me...

Am I missing something? or is this just not possible to do

Thanks

EDIT:

this is the whole block of code:

```
'clear the controls
    For Each element As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf element Is TextBox Then
            element.Text = ""
        End If
        If TypeOf element Is CheckBox Then
            element.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What type have you declared `element` as? If its just a `Control` then this is a base type for `CheckBox` that doesn't have the checked property. Maybe try:

```
If TypeOf element Is CheckBox Then
    DirectCast(element,CheckBox).checked = False
End If
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use `DirectCast` since it is only CheckBoxes or derived controls that will evaluate to True. This circumvents the added overhead of using `CType` as it sometimes has to coerce values into a different type. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703585/casting-datatypes-with-directcast-ctype-trycast/2703603#2703603) to one of my earlier questions ([Casting DataTypes with DirectCast, CType, TryCast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2703585/117870)).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
   For Each element As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf element Is TextBox Then
            element.Text = ""
        End If
        If TypeOf element Is CheckBox Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(element, CheckBox)
            chk.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
```