# What's the difference between CTYPE and DirectCast in Vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting DataTypes with DirectCast, CType, TryCast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703585/casting-datatypes-with-directcast-ctype-trycast)

I'm having a hard time understanding the real difference and when you should use which. Can somebody tell me the difference and maybe a couple of examples? Thanks?

Comment: This will soon be relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers