# Change a setting using a combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program, and I need to be able to change a setting using a combobox. I'm getting

*CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'FastColoredTextBoxNS.Language'. An explict conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*
Using the code:

```
        {
            fastColoredTextBox1.Language = comboBox1.SelectedItem
        }
```

Does anyone know a simple way to fix this? If any more info is needed, I will gladly edit it in.

Comment: You didn't mention what Items you added to that ComboBox or what its DataSource is. Did you add strings or the values of the enumerator (`[Enum].GetNames()`, `[Enum].GetValues()` or similar)

Comment: Also, is you question about VB or C#? The `{ }` are C#, the missing `;` points to `VB`. **CS____**  exceptions are C#.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast to the desired type, since the `SelectedItem` property returns the unspecific type `Object`.

```
fastColoredTextBox1.Language = DirectCast(comboBox1.SelectedItem, FastColoredTextBoxNS.Language)
```

Note there is also the `CType` function. In addition to performing type casts it also performs also type conversions. We do not need a conversion here, if the items in the ComboBox are of the required type. `DirectCast` just means, okay I know that the item with the runtime type `Object` is of the required type, just take it as such.

See also:

- [Casting DataTypes with DirectCast, CType, TryCast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2703585/880990)
- [Difference between DirectCast() and CType() in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3056514/880990)

Comment: Thank you for the help! It spits out cs0103 and cs0119 after i change the code

Comment: I have taken the type name `FastColoredTextBoxNS.Language` from the error message. Maybe you have import a namespace to make it work. Btw. These are C# error messages but you specified vb.net as tag. So the right answer for C# would be `fastColoredTextBox1.Language = (TheTypeNameHere)comboBox1.SelectedItem;`. The functions/operators `CType` and `DirectCast` are VB.