# How Do I convert C# Object Cast to VB.net Object Cast?(Specific Cast Method Shown)

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on getting the code below converted to VB.Net. What am I doing wrong here?

Code: Here is what I tried below. I tried Converting the following Statement:

```
(gotoAction.Destination, PDFPageDirectDestination).Page = destinationPage
            bookmark.Action = gotoAction
```

To this statement in the following Function: (I used DirectCast)

```
 Public Shared Function CreateBookmark(title As String, bookmarkColor As PDFRgbColor, visualStyle As PDFOutlineItemVisualStyle, destinationPage As PDFPage) As PDFOutlineItem

           
            Dim bookmark As PDFOutlineItem = New PDFOutlineItem()
            bookmark.Title = title
            bookmark.Color = bookmarkColor
           
            bookmark.VisualStyle = visualStyle

            Dim gotoAction As PDFGoToAction = New PDFGoToAction()
            
            gotoAction.Destination = New PDFPageDirectDestination()
            
            DirectCast(gotoAction.Destination, PDFPageDirectDestination).Page = destinationPage
            bookmark.Action = gotoAction

            Return bookmark
        End Function
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Where is the c# code ? The 1st snippet doesnt look like c#

Comment: Besides that, `DirectCast` is a **method** (`Function` in VB.NET) that returns the type-casted object. See [Casting DataTypes with DirectCast, CType, TryCast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703585/casting-datatypes-with-directcast-ctype-trycast)

Comment: @HelO'Ween Technically, `DirectCast` is still an operator, that just happens to also have method semantics.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, no casting needed:

```
Public Shared Function CreateBookmark(title As String, bookmarkColor As PDFRgbColor, visualStyle As PDFOutlineItemVisualStyle, destinationPage As PDFPage) As PDFOutlineItem          
     Dim bookmark As New PDFOutlineItem()
     bookmark.Title = title
     bookmark.Color = bookmarkColor          
     bookmark.VisualStyle = visualStyle

     Dim gotoAction As New PDFGoToAction()   
     Dim destination As New PDFPageDirectDestination()                   
     destination.Page = destinationPage
     gotoAction.Destination = destination
     bookmark.Action = gotoAction

     Return bookmark
End Function
```

Comment: This is so much cleaner. It worked perfectly. I used DirectCast , and it worked , but this is nicer.